# Why not to run Node.js and Neo4j on one Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, neo4j

I'm about to set up a server architecture on Amazon. I'm not familiar with best practices and pretty much learn as I go.

My boss told me to launch an Amazon EC2 instance with Node.js and Neo4j (Graph-Database) running on one and the same instance. Both should use different numbers of CPUs that are available. As the app grows bigger and need more resources, we would simply clone the instances. My boss doesn't have experience with this as well.

I must say I have a bad feeling about putting both Node.js and Neo4j on one instance / machine. I thought I would use the Amazon Linux HVM distro, since they got it set up to work fine with their services. Sadly, Neo4j is officially not supported by yum, but rather apt (Amazon Linux is based on Ubuntu and uses yum instead of apt). Therefore Neo4j recommends to use Debian/Ubuntu to run their database.

Why is it not a good idea to put both Node.js and Neo4j on one instance?

One reason I could imagine is that scalability is not as dynamic anymore as it would be with two separate instances running each service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scalability is probably the main reason.  I think by "node.js" here you mean an application written using node.js.   There's no problem with having the node.js package itself installed on the same machine where neo4j is running.

Figure that a good way to deploy neo4j is as a server, with your application talking to that server.  Sure, they could be on the same VM, but that would come with some complications:

- The security/firewall setting on that VM would have to be more complex, to account for all aspects of both co-existing.
- The memory/disk configuration would need to be sufficient for both.  If your app needs to grow, what happens when neo4j is eating a lot of the memory and not leaving much for your node app, or vice versa?

By splitting them out into two separate VMs, you can do performance tuning on them individually, to make sure that the one thing that's running there is running really well.  Later, if you need an HA cluster, you can make that single neo4j VM into a front for an HA cluster, and the node.js application can keep using the server as if nothing had changed.  So, scalability benefits there.

On security and networking config, splitting them into two VMs means you'll have to think through how to configure that correctly the first time.  You don't want just anybody being able to connect to your neo4j db, you want only your application to be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Those points make pretty much sense to me. By splitting both into two instances, I could have a security rule saying only the IP of my node instance would be allowed to connect to the neo4j instances.

Comment: And then you could freely scale your neo4j db without impacting any dependency on the app

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem is that computers running your database and computers running your code have different needs.

Node.js Code: Your code is stateless (meaning that it holds no data by itself). All of it's state is stored in the database. If there's a problem you can just restart the machine, or kill it and make a new identical machine running the same code, and no one will be able to tell the difference. If you need more scalability later on you can just move your code to a platform as a service such as AWS Elastic Beanstalk or Heroku which will manage this all for you. Just point it at your database.

Database: Needs to be persistent and durable. If you restart it, your entire application is down for the duration. If it gets corrupted, you lose all your data. While Neo4j has a high availability package which can help you manage some of this/spread the risk over multiple computers, it doesn't sound like you will be able to do this soon. Setting up the database computer and not touching it (to update node.js code) would make it less likely that anything would get screwed up. When you port to High Availability, it would make that transition more seamless as you won't have to find a new place to host your code.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I didn't have updating Node.js in mind yet and didn't think about Elastic Beanstalk at all.

Comment: When I refer to updating node.js code, I'm talking about the framework (though that is also important) I'm talking about updating the code itself. Assuming it's being done manually that will require copying the code and restarting the node.js server repeatedly every time you make a change (platform as service fixes this). You probably don't want to be sshing and constantly restarting programs on your more delicate database server.